# spring aop FastClassBySpringCGLIB vs EnhancerBySpringCGLIB

Tags: java, spring, aop, cglib

I have got an exception stacktrace, see picture below, in the stacktrace, there are $$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ and $$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$(underscored by light red color), they are for the same DAO class, I have @Transactional and @DataSource(for switch datasource) on DAO method. what is the difference between `Fast` and `Enhancer`? why need both of them?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is quite technical, so please forgive me if my answer is as well, pointing you to a nice [unofficial CGLIB manual](http://mydailyjava.blogspot.com/2013/11/cglib-missing-manual.html). There you can find all kinds of details about both `Enhancer` and `FastClass`. I will not quote them here.

If you do not want to read the manual (which I would understand), all you need to know is that these are the internal workings of CGLIB or how Spring chooses to use it, respectively.

Comment: The article is great, it helps me better understanding `Enhancer` and `FastClass`, thanks a lot.